# Printer driver not found

Tags: printing

I am unable to found Xerox work center 5225 multi functional machine driver for ubuntu 16.04.Kindly send me the link if anybody knows about it.

Comment: This one ? http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-5225/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en

Comment: this link I have already tried. It doesn't have a driver for ubuntu.